# How to rename multiple image at once while uploading

Tags: php, image-uploading

I'm firstly describing this code, what it does

```
/**
* Stores any image uploaded from the edit form
*
* @param assoc The 'image' element from the $_FILES array containing the file upload data
*/ 

public function storeUploadedImage( $image ) {

if ( $image['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK )
{
  // Does the Article object have an ID?
  if ( is_null( $this->id ) ) trigger_error( "Article::storeUploadedImage(): Attempt to upload an image for an Article object that does not have its ID property set.", E_USER_ERROR );

  // Delete any previous image(s) for this article
  $this->deleteImages();

  // Get and store the image filename extension
  $this->imageExtension = strtolower( strrchr( $image['name'], '.' ) );

  // Store the image

  $tempFilename = trim( $image['tmp_name'] );

  if ( is_uploaded_file ( $tempFilename ) ) {
    if ( !( move_uploaded_file( $tempFilename, $this->getImagePath() ) ) ) trigger_error( "Article::storeUploadedImage(): Couldn't move uploaded file.", E_USER_ERROR );
    if ( !( chmod( $this->getImagePath(), 0666 ) ) ) trigger_error( "Article::storeUploadedImage(): Couldn't set permissions on uploaded file.", E_USER_ERROR );
  }

  // Get the image size and type
  $attrs = getimagesize ( $this->getImagePath() );
  $imageWidth = $attrs[0];
  $imageHeight = $attrs[1];
  $imageType = $attrs[2];

  // Load the image into memory
  switch ( $imageType ) {
    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
      $imageResource = imagecreatefromgif ( $this->getImagePath() );
      break;
    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
      $imageResource = imagecreatefromjpeg ( $this->getImagePath() );
      break;
    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
      $imageResource = imagecreatefrompng ( $this->getImagePath() );
      break;
    default:
      trigger_error ( "Article::storeUploadedImage(): Unhandled or unknown image type ($imageType)", E_USER_ERROR );
  }

  // Copy and resize the image to create the thumbnail
  $thumbHeight = intval ( $imageHeight / $imageWidth * ARTICLE_THUMB_WIDTH );
  $thumbResource = imagecreatetruecolor ( ARTICLE_THUMB_WIDTH, $thumbHeight );
  imagecopyresampled( $thumbResource, $imageResource, 0, 0, 0, 0, ARTICLE_THUMB_WIDTH, $thumbHeight, $imageWidth, $imageHeight );

  // Save the thumbnail
  switch ( $imageType ) {
    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
      imagegif ( $thumbResource, $this->getImagePath( IMG_TYPE_THUMB ) );
      break;
    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
      imagejpeg ( $thumbResource, $this->getImagePath( IMG_TYPE_THUMB ), JPEG_QUALITY );
      break;
    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
      imagepng ( $thumbResource, $this->getImagePath( IMG_TYPE_THUMB ) );
      break;
    default:
      trigger_error ( "Article::storeUploadedImage(): Unhandled or unknown image type ($imageType)", E_USER_ERROR );
  }

  $this->update();
}
}


/**
* Deletes any images and/or thumbnails associated with the article
*/

public function deleteImages() {

// Delete all fullsize images for this article
foreach (glob( ARTICLE_IMAGE_PATH . "/" . IMG_TYPE_FULLSIZE . "/" . $this->id . ".*") as $filename) {
  if ( !unlink( $filename ) ) trigger_error( "Article::deleteImages(): Couldn't delete image file.", E_USER_ERROR );
}

// Delete all thumbnail images for this article
foreach (glob( ARTICLE_IMAGE_PATH . "/" . IMG_TYPE_THUMB . "/" . $this->id . ".*") as $filename) {
  if ( !unlink( $filename ) ) trigger_error( "Article::deleteImages(): Couldn't delete thumbnail file.", E_USER_ERROR );
}

// Remove the image filename extension from the object
$this->imageExtension = "";
}


/**
* Returns the relative path to the article's full-size or thumbnail image
*
* @param string The type of image path to retrieve (IMG_TYPE_FULLSIZE or IMG_TYPE_THUMB). Defaults to IMG_TYPE_FULLSIZE.
* @return string|false The image's path, or false if an image hasn't been uploaded
*/

public function getImagePath( $type=IMG_TYPE_FULLSIZE ) {
return ( $this->id && $this->imageExtension ) ? ( ARTICLE_IMAGE_PATH . "/$type/" . $this->id . $this->imageExtension ) : false;
}
```

1. It uploads one image and one thumbnail per article
2. Rename the image (for ex. if the database article id is 5, the full size and thumbnail image after renaming will be 5)

I want to modify a CMS which allows only one image to upload per article. So all my intention is to upload 5 image per article.

And my 2nd intention is to rename each file in accordance with article title (for ex. if the article title is Nokia N9, the 1st image while uploading will be nokia_n9_1.jpg, the 2nd will be nokia_n9_2.jpg and the left also be as 1st and 2nd.

I'm new in PHP OOP. I know it's quite a bit of work to be done. Helps will be greatly appreciated.
If you want to see full CMS source code, check the link

http://www.elated.com/articles/cms-in-an-afternoon-php-mysql/

http://www.elated.com/articles/add-image-uploading-to-your-cms/

Answer (score 0):

Actually  it is not about OOP to make this changes):

So in admin.php you have this:

```
// User has posted the article edit form: save the new article
 $article = new Article;
 $article->storeFormValues( $_POST );
 $article->insert();
 if ( isset( $_FILES['image'] ) ) $article->storeUploadedImage( $_FILES['image'] );
 header( "Location: admin.php?status=changesSaved" );
```

Consider reading this http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php to understand the changes we will made. So modify admin php to this:

```
// User has posted the article edit form: save the new article
  $article = new Article;
  $article->storeFormValues( $_POST );
  $article->insert();
  if ( isset( $_FILES['image'] ) ) $article->storeUploadedImage( $_FILES['image'], '1' );
  if ( isset( $_FILES['image2'] ) ) $article->storeUploadedImage( $_FILES['image2'], '2' );
  if ( isset( $_FILES['image3'] ) ) $article->storeUploadedImage( $_FILES['image3'], '3' );
  if ( isset( $_FILES['image4'] ) ) $article->storeUploadedImage( $_FILES['image4'], '4' );
  if ( isset( $_FILES['image5'] ) ) $article->storeUploadedImage( $_FILES['image5'], '5' );
  header( "Location: admin.php?status=changesSaved" );
```

Modify article.php:

Find this

```
public function storeUploadedImage( $image ) {
```

Change to this:

```
public function storeUploadedImage( $image, $postfix ) {
```

Also find this:

```
  if ( is_uploaded_file ( $tempFilename ) ) {
     if ( !( move_uploaded_file( $tempFilename, $this->getImagePath() ) ) ) trigger_error( "Article::storeUploadedImage(): Couldn't move uploaded file.", E_USER_ERROR );
     if ( !( chmod( $this->getImagePath(), 0666 ) ) ) trigger_error( "Article::storeUploadedImage(): Couldn't set permissions on uploaded file.", E_USER_ERROR );
  }
```

And change to this:

```
  $image_name = implode( '_', explode( ' ', $this->title ) ) . '_' . $postfix; 
  if ( is_uploaded_file ( $tempFilename ) ) {
     if ( !( move_uploaded_file( $tempFilename, $this->getImagePath( IMG_TYPE_FULLSIZE, $image_name ) ) ) ) trigger_error( "Article::storeUploadedImage(): Couldn't move uploaded file.", E_USER_ERROR );
     if ( !( chmod( $this->getImagePath(IMG_TYPE_FULLSIZE, $image_name), 0666 ) ) ) trigger_error( "Article::storeUploadedImage(): Couldn't set permissions on uploaded file.", E_USER_ERROR );
  }
```

And finally replace getImagePath method (function) with this:

```
public function getImagePath( $type=IMG_TYPE_FULLSIZE, $title = null ) {
    if( $title !== null )
    {
        return ( $this->imageExtension ) ? ( ARTICLE_IMAGE_PATH . "/$type/" . $title . $this->imageExtension ) : false;
    }
    else
    { 
        return ( $this->id && $this->imageExtension ) ? ( ARTICLE_IMAGE_PATH . "/$type/" . $this->id . $this->imageExtension ) : false;
    }
}
```

You must also modify your form for uploading image:

```
      <li>
        <label for="image">New Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="image" id="image" placeholder="Choose an image to upload" maxlength="255" />
        <label for="image2">New Image2</label>
        <input type="file" name="image2" id="image2" placeholder="Choose an image to upload" maxlength="255" />
        ...
      </li>
```